# SQL: tricky join

Tags: sql, join

I'm building software for exam signup and grading:

I need to get data from these two tables:

Exams

```
|------------------------------------------------------------|           
| ExamId  |  ExamTitle  |  EducationId  |  ExamDate  |               
|------------------------------------------------------------|
```

ExamAttempts

```
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| ExamAttemptId  |  ExamId  |  StudentId  |  Grade  |  NotPresentCode  |        
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

1. Students attends an education
2. Educations have multiple exams
3. Students have up to 6 attempts per exam
4. Every attempt is graded or marked as not present

Students can sign up for an exam if:
- not passed yet (grade below 2)
- has not used all attempts

I want to list every exams that a student can sign up for.

It maybe fairly simple, but I just can't get my head around it and now I'm stuck! I've tried EVERYTHING but haven't got it right yet. This is one of the more hopeless tries I made (!):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getExamsOpenForSignUp
@EducationId int,
@StudentId int
AS
SELECT ex.*
FROM Exams ex
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ExamId, COUNT(ExamId) AS NumAttempts
    FROM ExamAttempts
    WHERE StudentId = @StudentId AND grade < 2 OR grade IS NULL
    GROUP BY ExamId
) exGrouped ON ex.ExamId = exGrouped.ExamId
WHERE educationid = @EducationId and exGrouped.ExamId IS NULL OR exGrouped.NumAttempts < 6;
GO
```

What am i doing wrong? Please help...

Comment: Please post the DDL for the two tables (not just a list of columns that can't even easily be massaged into DDL), a bit of sample data (as plain INSERTs to the tables), the desired result and preferably the result of executing your query. **SSCCE** (short, self-contained, correct example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start with a list of all possibilities of exams and students and then weed out the ones that don't meet the requirements.

```
select driver.StudentId, driver.ExamId
from (select @StudentId as StudentId, e.ExamId
      from exams e
      where e.EducationId = @EducationId
     ) driver left outer join
     (select ea.ExamId, ea.StudentId
      from ExamAttempts ea
      group by ea.ExamId, ea.StudentId
      having max(grade) >= 2 or -- passed
             count(*) >= 6
     ) NotEligible
     on driver.ExamId = NotEligible.ExamId and
        driver.StudentId = NotEligible.StudentId
where NotEligible.ExamId is NULL
```

The structure of this query is quite specific.  The `driver` table contains all possible combinations.  In this case, you have only one student and all exams are in the "education".  Then the left join determines which are *not* eligible, based on your two requirements.  The final `where` is selecting the non-matches to the not-eligible -- or the exams that are eligible.

Comment: Sorry this gives me all tables no matter if exams are passed or attempted too many times. The Left Join does that, right? It gives me all of the rows in the left (driver) table no matter if there are any matches in the NotEligible... At least, that's how I understand the left join???

Comment: @olefrank . . . Yes, that is how the `left outer join` works.  And then the `where` clause filters out the invalid exams.  I may have had the logic backwards on the `passed` variable.  The `having` clause should have whatever the passed condition is.

Comment: Sorry, it seems to be working perfectly! Thanks for the very nice explanation also, you're the man :)

Comment: This is not correct answer - it will count attempt of other students too.

Comment: @YK1 . . . You were right.  The join on the attempts (NotEligible) inadvertently left out the student id (or a filter on `StudentId = @StudentId`).

Answer (score 1):

Check if this works in your SP:

```
Select EduExams.ExamId
from
    (select * from Exams 
     where Exams.EducationId = @EducationId) EduExams 
left outer join 
    (select * from ExamAttempts 
     where ExamAttempts.StudentId = @StudentId) StudentAttempts
on EduExams.ExamID = StudentAttempts.ExamId
group by EduExams.ExamId
having count(StudentAttempts.ExamAttemptId) < 6 
       and ((max(StudentAttempts.Grade) is null) or (max(StudentAttempts.Grade) < 2))
```

Comment: Thanks this also works! But leave out the last closing ')' :)

Comment: no actually I missed the opening one right after 'and' - updated answer - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK thank you both for your help - much appreciated!

Based on @Gordon Linoffs solution. this is what I ended up with:

```
SELECT driver.ExamId, driver.ExamTitle
FROM (
    SELECT @StudentId AS StudentId, e.ExamId, e.ExamTitle
    FROM exams e
    WHERE e.EducationId = @EducationId
) driver 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT ea.ExamId, ea.StudentId
        FROM ExamAttempts ea
        WHERE ea.studentId = @StudentId
        GROUP BY ea.ExamId, ea.StudentId
        HAVING MAX(grade) >= 2 OR COUNT(*) >= 6
    ) NotEligible
        ON driver.ExamId = NotEligible.ExamId AND driver.StudentId = NotEligible.StudentId
WHERE NotEligible.ExamId IS NULL
```